# Coloring dgCMatrix image by factor in R

Tags: r, visualization

I am trying to color a sparse matrix image according to a grouping factor. I know the solution is related to matrix coloring in the lattice package but I have troubles to handle it.

I have a list of hits on an app list. Every hit is related to a user and a app at a specific time.
- On the y axis are users sorted by first install of the app
          Every user then has a new line for his pages hits
- On the x axis is the time
Points are hits

Here is a preview of the data:
    library(Matrix)

```
   indexUser indexInstall time
1          1            1    3
2          1            1   17
3          1            1   19
4          1            1   32
5          1            1   81
6          1            1   86
7          1            1  124
8          1            1  231
9          1            1  233
10         1            2  249
11         2            3    4
12         2            3    6
13         2            3    7
14         2            3   15
15         2            3   25
16         2            3   32
17         2            3   45
18         2            3   74
19         2            3   75
20         3            4   36
21         3            4   37
22         3            4  113
23         4            5   69
24         4            5   70
25         4            5   71
```

I then create a sparse matrix as the full dataset is way larger than that (10000+ x 1000)

```
sM <- sparseMatrix(i=dat$indexInstall, j=dat$time, x=1)
```

And show an image of it:

```
image(sM)
```

I want to color every lines according to the indexUser column. For example to plot user 1 in blue and all others un red

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you clarify if when you write "I know the solution is related to matrix coloring in the lattice package but I have troubles to handle it." you either a) want a solution not using the lattice package because you have reasons not shown here that force you to **not** use it or b) you would like to have us suggest a lattice package based solution and only wanted to show - as greatly appreciated -your alternate trials? Thanks.

Comment: This webpage mentions it    http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/Matrix/man/image-methods.html . I had like to plot it with this function but I can't handle it

Comment: Ah, ok: The underlying implementation **uses** functions from the `lattice` package. Thanks for the clarification.